# How to remove tab icon image for a site?

Tags: html, css, icons, favicon

I am currently using skeleton framework,
www.getskeleton.com
 while building a website but the skeleton image is displaying as a favicon on the web page's tab. I deleted the image itself and checked all the link, rel, tags and meta tags in the html page and css page to see if anything was pointing towards an image but there's nothing to suggest why it is still there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The path of the favicon is `dist/images/favicon.png`.

Ensure if the favicon is deleted from this path.

Also try clearing browser cache and hard refresh the webiste `Ctrl + F5`.

Comment: No, I'd already done that. I think it is a problem with Brackets specifically although not sure how exactly. It was fetching the file even though there is no code for it to try to make it fetch.